# Make some parts of TextField Editable

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textinputfield, flutter-textformfield

So I have this unique requirement as shown in the picture below, where the blue texts are user inputs. I have been doing my own research regarding this and have found a few viable solutions, out of which a custom `TextEditingController` seems most promising. I haven't started implementation but out of the top of my head, I think I might run into some problems with the touch and cursor controls later on.

Now my question is, Is there a better way that I might have overlooked? Is there a way to gracefully handle which areas are touchable, handle the cursor when deleting, and moving to the next focus?

[image]

Comment: Our thinking could be wrong/right, but after applying our thoughts into code-structure, we face many issues. Then we look and ask by showing errors that  we get from applied code. Can you apply your thoughts and share the issue with code-snippet?

Comment: You might try to use `Wrap` widget with `Text` and `TextField` as children

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Currently in the drafting stage and collecting valid solutions or possible steps before diving in. I would definitely be posting updates.

As for now, I have gathered that `TextEditingController` can definitely be used for creating individual spans as I've gone through some of the libraries that do something similar. And with the help of `TextSelectionControls` and `TextEditingValue`, it definitely seems feasible.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Andrey Gordeev, we can use a `Wrap Widget` with a `children` defined as follows:

```
Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  children: [
    const Text('Hala, we\'re '),
    SizedBox(
      width: 50,
      height: 20,
      child: TextField(
        controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(
          const TextEditingValue(text: 'aryab'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    const Text(' You? I\'m '),
    SizedBox(
      width: 150,
      height: 20,
      child: TextField(
        controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(
          const TextEditingValue(text: 'Someone Awesome'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

This renders the result of the screenshot attached:

[image: screenshot]

A full example snippet can be found below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: 
        Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
          runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('Hala, we\'re '),
            SizedBox(
              width: 50,
              height: 20,
              child: TextField(
                controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(
                  const TextEditingValue(text: 'aryab'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Text(' You? I\'m '),
            SizedBox(
              width: 150,
              height: 20,
              child: TextField(
                controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(
                  const TextEditingValue(text: 'Someone Awesome'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, definitely a much cleaner implementation. Will run this through the team, for now, I can foresee that the TextField won't flow to the next line breaking it up, which might be a point of rejection. This can definitely be something I can fall back to if the `TextEditingController` doesn't go as planned.

Answer (score 2):

While there are two types of widgets, `<plainText,inputText>` can be placed here, and we need to concern about retrieving full text from the form/text.

Creating a map for the widgets will be a good choice, I think.

```dart
  final Map<String, String?> _textsInForm = {
    "Hala, we're": null,
    "aryab": "groupName",
    ". You? I'm": null,
    "Someone Awysome": "myself",
    ",a": null,
    "Driver": "job",
  };
```

As you can see, I'm using `key` as main value and `value` as nullable string. If we find null-string, it will be simply `Text` widget, else `TextFiled`.

I'm using `RichText` to handle this situation.

We will create list `List<InlineSpan>` for `RichText` and `List<TextEditingController>` to handle input text.

I'm using `StatelessWidget`, while having `stateFullWidget` handle creation on `initState`.

There is one issue, it is taking minimum hint text width. You can try with passing text on `TextEditingController` instead.

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SomeTextEditable extends StatelessWidget {
  SomeTextEditable({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final Map<String, String?> _textsInForm = {
    "Hala, we're": null,
    "aryab": "groupName",
    ". You? I'm": null,
    "Someone Awysome": "myself",
    ",a": null,
    "Driver": "job",
  };

  final TextStyle _hintTextStyle = const TextStyle(
    color: Colors.grey,
  );

  final TextStyle _textFiledStyle = const TextStyle(
    color: Colors.blue,
  );

  WidgetSpan _textFiled(TextEditingController controller, String hint) =>
      WidgetSpan(
        alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle, // set middle according to texts
        child: IntrinsicWidth(
          //flexiable size
          child: TextField(
            style: _textFiledStyle,
            controller: controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintStyle: _hintTextStyle,
              hintText: hint,
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];

    List<InlineSpan> textSpans = [];

    _textsInForm.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value != null) {
        TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

        controllers.add(controller);
        textSpans.add(_textFiled(controller, key));
      } else {
        textSpans.add(TextSpan(text: "$key "));
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          RichText(
            text: TextSpan(children: textSpans),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              String result = "";
              int i = 0;

              _textsInForm.forEach((key, value) {
                if (value != null) {
                  final textFromIcontroller = controllers[i++].text;
                  result += "$textFromIcontroller ";
                } else {
                  result += "$key ";
                }
              });

              print(result);
            },
            child: Text("Get Text"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```